# Relation between negative part of function and another function.

Tags: analysis

I'm wondering how works this fact.
Let be $f:= f^+ - f^-$ and $g$ a function such that $g \le f$.
Then $f^- \le |g|$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x) \geq 0$, then $f^-(x)=0$ so $f^-(x) \leq |g(x)|$.

If $f(x) \leq 0$, then $f^-(x)=-f(x) \leq -g(x) = |g(x)|$ because $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq 0$.

If both cases, you get $f^-(x) \leq |g(x)|$, so
$$f^- \leq |g|$$

Comment: sorry, my fault. I forgot the equality.

Comment: @Gyro Ok I edited